# Eclipse Fails to load on Windows 32 Bit computer

Tags: eclipse, windows

I have tried the suggestion eclipse -clean
I then blew away the workspace and reloaded latest Eclipse Mars
Eclipse creates a new workspace and gets same error as I do with my old workspace 
All was good when I was running a 64/32 bit windows system. 
Rebuilt windows computer for only 32 bit `enter code here`
Now when I start Eclipse my log file gets following:

```
!SESSION 2015-07-31 16:48:17.649 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.5.0.I20150603-2000
java.version=1.8.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2015-07-31 16:48:22.360
!MESSAGE Unable to load resource platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.platform/LegacyIDE.e4xmi
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1DiagnosticWrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.XMIException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.platform/LegacyIDE.e4xmi; systemId: platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.platform/LegacyIDE.e4xmi; lineNumber: 2; Undeclared prefix: "xmi:version". (platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.platform/LegacyIDE.e4xmi, 2, -1)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.handleDemandLoadException(ResourceSetImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.getResource(ResourceHandler.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadResource(ResourceHandler.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.XMIException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.platform/LegacyIDE.e4xmi; systemId: platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.platform/LegacyIDE.e4xmi; lineNumber: 2; Undeclared prefix: "xmi:version". (platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.platform/LegacyIDE.e4xmi, 2, -1)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.toXMIException(XMLHandler.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.error(XMLHandler.java:699)
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.Parser2.error(Parser2.java:3018)
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.Parser2.processName(Parser2.java:1581)
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.Parser2.processAttributeNS(Parser2.java:1553)
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.Parser2.maybeElement(Parser2.java:1410)
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.Parser2.parseInternal(Parser2.java:499)
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.Parser2.parse(Parser2.java:304)
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl.parse(XMLReaderImpl.java:433)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.doLoad(XMLResourceImpl.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1518)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1297)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:274)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.platform/LegacyIDE.e4xmi; systemId: platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.platform/LegacyIDE.e4xmi; lineNumber: 2; Undeclared prefix: "xmi:version".
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.Parser2.error(Parser2.java:3013)
    ... 36 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-07-31 16:48:22.376
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to delete .metadata folder and it will not effect to your projects.

Thanks

Comment: This should be a comment